# PHP: Recuperar ID de uma URL Simplificada

Tags: php

Tenho uma URL assim: http://localhost/oficina2/home.php?id=12345
Estou simplificando para: http://localhost/oficina2/?12345

Como eu recupero essa id (12345) em alguma página?

Eu tentei assim: $url = $_GET['id'];

Mas dá o seuinte erro: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\oficina2\home.php on line 2

Comment: podia fazer simplesmente `http://endereco/oficina.php/12345` ja de uma vez e pegar o valor com `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` (lembrando de tirar as barras da string) - Ou então renomear o `home.php` para o nome padrão do seu servidor de páginas se já nao for (geralmente `index.html` no Apache) e usar `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` para obter o numero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Recomendado e você usar url amigavel você pode fazer da seguinte maneira redirecionar todo seu trafego para index e nela gerenciar as views de acordo com a url passada 
exemplo 
HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Na sua pagina index

```
//recupera a url
$GetURL = strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_DEFAULT))); 

//explode a url pela barra 
$URL = array_filter(explode('/', $GetURL));
```

você recupera o valor echo $URL[1];